# How to use negative values in which() statement in R?

Tags: r

I want to exclude the rows in which `x` has values less than or equal to -10, so I wrote this:

```
newdata <- data[which(data$x> -10), ]
```

Is this right or I need to put -10 in double quotation marks?

Thank you.

Comment: That's fine, or just `newdata <- data[data$x > -10,]`

Comment: In the future, please try running your code in R before asking a basic query. It kind of defeats the purpose of having an interactive program.

Answer (score 2):

(Decided to upgrade this from a comment to an answer.)

- Using double quotation marks is *not* wise: it will mess you up in some quite surprising ways. For example, `1 > "-10"` is `FALSE` (!!) because of the way in which R compares strings.
- R's use of `<-` for assignment *may* get you in trouble; if you want `x<-10` to do the comparison rather than assign the value 10 to `x`, you need either spaces `x < -10` or parentheses (`x<(-10)`).  However, this doesn't arise with the `>` comparison.
- You can always use parentheses if you're worried (`x > (-10)`); the only drawback is that things get harder to read if you use too many (e.g., `data[(which(((data$x)>(-10)))),])`).
- As pointed out in the comments, R is an *interactive* environment; if you can't figure something like this out from the documentation or other help sources, you should just try a small example and convince yourself that it works.

For example:

```
 x <- c(-20,-15,-10,-4,0)
 x[x>-10]
 ## -4 0
```